# Correlation between selection of columns in df using a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, correlation

I have a dataframe (`df`) with 8 columns.  I'd like to use a `for` loop to calculate Pearson correlation for a selection of columns the following way:

```
cor1=cor(df[,1], df[,2])
cor2=cor(df[,3], df[,4])
```

and so on. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is just to compute the correlation matrix, then you can index it if you want:

```
df <- data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
corMat <- cor(df)
```

For example, correlation between variables 1 and 2:

```
corMat[1,2]
```

Or do you really need to have specific correlations in separate objects?

## Edit

Here is a for loop example of what you want:

```
df <- data.frame(rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10),rnorm(10))

for (i in seq(1,ncol(df),by=2))
{
    assign(paste("cor",i/2+0.5,sep=""),cor(df[,i],df[,i+1]))
}
```

Though it is quite inefficient.

Comment: Hallo Sascha, thank you very much for your comment. But it has to be a for-loop that computes correlations for each pair of variables, e.g. 1) cor1=cor (col1,col2), cor2=cor (col3,col4) and so on..

Comment: Why does it has to be a for loop? That is very inefficient programming in R. If this is a homework assignment please tag it as such. Anyway, edited a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` with a generalized function :

```
df<-data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c1=rnorm(10),d=rnorm(10))
f<- function(x) {
  cc=x[1] #column index
  if (cc<ncol(df)){
    cor(x[-1],df[,cc+1]) #ignore 1st element [-1]
  }
}

apply(rbind(1:dim(df)[2], 2, f) #apply over columns after adding a column id numbers at the top row
```

May be there is a R function to get column/row id inside apply function? In that case, we don't need to rbind the column ids.